# Getting started with an LPC1313 Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, programming, rs232, lpc

I recently purchased [this microcontroller](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/cortex_m3/LPC1313FBD48.html#quickreference) along with an FTDI TTL-232R-3V3 cable. I want to program a blinking lights hello world application onto the microcontroller. I was told that I might be able to do this with flash magic. How could I do this?

Any help would be much appreciated as I am very new to this!

Comment: Is this a bare chip or a development board?

Comment: @alexan_e a bare chip

Comment: If a bare chip, then why this chip? A DIP chip (LPC1114FN28) will be much easier for a starter!

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I just got a random one to see how it works. I am very intent on seeing this one perform some kind of task

Comment: If it was a random choice there is no reason to stick with this one if it takes more effort than switching. Either get a DIP chip, or get a development board.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen But for in the interim, how could I make this MCU work?

Comment: In order to do something with the chip you have to solder it to a PCB board with proper supply, capacitors etc. Have you worked with SMD parts before, know how to solder them?

Comment: @alexan_e Well I did get [a pcb](http://www.nkcelectronics.com/lqfp48-breakout-boa48.html) and some female pins to work with the cable

Comment: And have you soldered the chip on the board?

Comment: not yet but I do have solder paste

Comment: @user3131007 In cases like these, people here on the EE.SE usually say that we should walk before you try to run. It seems to me that the chip you got is for running. I'm a newbie and I'm working with microcontrollers for a year, and I'm still working with through-hole parts, yours is an SMD. I know some people will hate me for saying that, but have you thought about starting up with an Arduino board and an ATmega328 instead. They are much easier to start with. I, myself, wouldn't be here is it wasn't for Arduino. Then you can set apart this MCU you got for when you are ready for it.

Comment: @Ricardo I haven't gotten it to run yet. I haven't gotten it to do anything yet. I don't even know what the "Xtal Frequency" for this MCU is! I'm trying to learn more about how to make this MCU run and at least make it blink an LED.

Comment: @user<some number>: Ricardo was being mild. Don't try to fly before you learned to crawl. If you are set on Cortex chips (good choice IMO), get an LPC1114FN28. If not, get a chip (any chip!) that you can get support for in your neighborhood. If you are not set on using a bare chip, get a development board. An Arduino is definitely not a bad choice. Save this LPC chip for later.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Ok. What would you suggest? I am interested by bare cortex chips.

Comment: As I said, LPC1114FN28. It is in DIP28. Serial downloading works the same as with your LPC1343.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would highly recommend getting a development board. The LPC Xpresso stuff is very cheap, and has a build in method to program the chip, for example, here is a cheap board for the LPC13xx series: http://www.nxp.com/demoboard/OM11048.html

With that being said, if you want to 'go it alone', the way to do it is to design a bare-boards circuit that has power and the serial pins (RX/TX) going to the FTDI USB->Serial adapter. You will at a minimum need to hook up power, ground, reset, have a switch for PIO0_1 (to be able to choose between the bootloader and the application code), tie PIO0_3 to ground (for serial based bootloader), and hook up RX and TX to the corresponding pins on the FTDI adapter.

Check out document UM10375 chapter 21 (specifically 21.4) for more info on the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Forget Flash Magic, unless you are a GUI-lover. LPC21ISP offers the same functionality, but from the command line, so it can be automated. Additionally, it can start a serial terminal (using the same lines used to download the image), so you can print to the UART to get debug info to your PC.

Comment: I am on a mac and was told that it would be the best option